# Problem: Jquery printing close window immediately after open

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, printing

In some Chrome browsers when the user click on the print button immediately close.

My code was :

```
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write("some content");
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

I'v tried:

```
newWin.focus();
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

And:

```
setTimeout(function () { newWin.print(); }, 500);
newWin.onfocus = function () { setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 500); }
```

And:

```
var document_focus = false; // var we use to monitor document focused status.

// Now our event handlers.
$(document).ready(function() { newWin.window.print();document_focus = true; });
setInterval(function() { if (document_focus === true) { newWin.window.close(); }  }, 300);
```

But non of them worked and the print window still closes.

How can i prevent the print window closes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around it with iFrame

The iFrame:

```
 <iframe id="print_this_iframe" hidden></iframe>
```

The Jquery:

```
var dstFrame = document.getElementById('print_this_iframe');
var dstDoc = dstFrame.contentDocument || dstFrame.contentWindow.document;
dstDoc.write('Some Content');
dstDoc.close();
dstFrame.onload = function() { $("#print_this_iframe").get(0).contentWindow.print()};
```